# Stack multiple Landsat images

Tags: python, bash, gdal, landsat, rasterio

I would like to stack around 700 Landsat images in specific [format](https://github.com/ceholden/landsat_stack) as input to [YATSM](https://github.com/ceholden/yatsm) Continuous change detection and classification (CCDC) algorithm. I try to use this bash script [`4_stack_TIFF.sh`](https://github.com/valpasq/landsat_dataset/blob/master/4_stack_TIFF.sh). In this script, the stacking is done using this file [`landsat_stack.py`](https://github.com/ceholden/misc/blob/master/landsat/landsat_stack.py). I'm getting two errors:

- First is related to the lack of a module `module load batch_landsat`. I could find this the shared repositiries
- Second is related to `landsat_stack.py`, I get the following:
  `Stacking to extent: Traceback (most recent call last): File "./landsat_stack.py", line 936, in <module> sys.exit(main()) File "./landsat_stack.py", line 920, in main utm, resume, fformat, creation_opts)) File "./landsat_stack.py", line 757, in landsat_stack print('\tUpper Left: {ulx},{uly}'.format(ulx=extent[0], uly=extent[1])) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable Done!`

**Questions:**

1. Is there someone who have used YATSM and faced the same issue in landsat data pre-processing?
2. if not; Can you suggest me a solution using Rasterio or Rio?

**Format:**

```
8 band images: 
   Band 1 SR (SR * 10000)
   Band 2 SR (SR * 10000)
   Band 3 SR (SR * 10000)
   Band 4 SR (SR * 10000)
   Band 5 SR (SR * 10000)
   Band 7 SR (SR * 10000)
   Band 6 Thermal Brightness (C * 100)
   Fmask
       0 - clear land
       1 - clear water
       2 - cloud
       3 - snow
       4 - shadow
       255 - NoData
```